# Which set do these parts belong to? - Red Robot from 90s or early 00s?

Tags: set-identification

[image: Set parts]

Does anyone know the name of this set? I found these loose parts in a crate and I would like to piece the set back together.

I think I received this set either very late 90s or early 00s. (probably before 2005 if that helps)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are parts from the [7314: Recon Mech RP](https://brickset.com/sets/7314-1/Recon-Mech-RP) set, from the [Life on Mars theme](https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Space/subtheme-Life-On-Mars), released in 2001.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!